# Azure Service Principals are not deleting from the Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-service-principal, entra

I'm executing the code below, and it appears that the delete method isn't able to detect all the service principals like the list method does. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **`az ad sp list`** by default lists only the first 100 Service Principals. Hence you need to use **`--all`** flag to list all the Service Principals.

Hence **to resolve the error**, you need to modify the script by using **`az ad sp list --all --query "[].appId" -o tsv`** like below:

```bash
sp_list=$(az ad sp list --all --query "[].appId" -o tsv)
for sp_id in $sp_list;do
    echo "Deleting service principal: $sp_id" 
    az ad sp delete --id $sp_id
done
echo "All Service Principals deleted"
```

For **sample**, I tried to delete few Service Principals by using **`-all`** flag *(as I cannot delete all Service Principals in my environment)*:

I tried to delete the below applications:

[image]

**The service principals got deleted successfully:**

```bash
sp_list=$(az ad sp list --all --query "[?displayName=='cli1' || displayName=='cli2' || displayName=='cli3' || displayName=='cli4' || displayName=='cli5'].appId" -o tsv)
for sp_id in $sp_list;do
    echo "Deleting service principal: $sp_id" 
    az ad sp delete --id $sp_id
done
echo "All Service Principals deleted"
```

[image]

Comment: I have all the necessary service principals. However, when my code queries these service principals and attempts to delete them, it encounters an error stating that the principals do not exist.

Comment: Rukmini, I added -all flag and got the same result. Your suggestion doesn't seem logical because the delete function employs the ID of a service principal already retrieved by az ad sp list. Therefore, searching for additional IDs is misguided.

Comment: Initially in my environment I got the same error, after using -all flag I got the results that is service principles for deleted